# Java nio, close socketChannel but leave ServerSocketChannel opened

Tags: java, nio

I have a server app. Java NIO

I have Runnable class - EventHandler - that process incoming messages. If message == "Bye" -> EventHandler close related SocketServer and SelectorKey

I have one Runnable object - Acceptor - that is activated on OP_ACCEPT events. It creates new SocketChannel and new EventHandler to process messages from this channel

I have a problem.
First client connect. Send messages. Disconnect. Everything is ok

After first client disconnected Second client connect. Here problem begins - Acceptor object isn't invoked, therefore SocketChannel and EventHandler are not created for new client.

What is wrong in my code? SocketChannel closed improperly?

---

### I changed the code to fix the errors that were noted in the comments. Now it works fine

Reactor. Class with the main loop

```
public class Reactor implements Runnable {

    final Selector selector;
    final ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;

    Reactor(int port) throws IOException {
        //configure server socket channel
        this.selector = Selector.open();
        this.serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        this.serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        this.serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        //start acceptor
        this.serverSocketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT, new Acceptor(this.serverSocketChannel, this.selector));
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Server is listening to port: " + serverSocketChannel.socket().getLocalPort());
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (this.selector.select() > 0) {
                    Set<SelectionKey> selected = this.selector.selectedKeys();
                    for (SelectionKey selectionKey : selected) {
                        dispatch(selectionKey);
                    }
                    selected.clear(); //clear set (thanks to EJP for comment)
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void dispatch(SelectionKey k) {
        Runnable r = (Runnable) (k.attachment());
        if (r != null) {
            r.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Acceptor

```
public class Acceptor implements Runnable {

    final ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;
    final Selector selector;

    public Acceptor(ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel, Selector selector) {
        this.serverSocketChannel = serverSocketChannel;
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            SocketChannel socketChannel = this.serverSocketChannel.accept();
            if (socketChannel != null) {
                new EventHandler(this.selector, socketChannel);
                System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EventHandler

```
public class EventHandler implements Runnable {

    EventHandler(Selector selector, SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {
        this.socketChannel = socketChannel;
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        this.selectionKey = this.socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, this);
        //selector.wakeup();  //we don't need to wake up selector (thanks to EJP for comment)
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (this.state == EventHandlerStatus.READING) {
                read();
            } else if (this.state == EventHandlerStatus.SENDING) {
                send();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reading client message
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void read() throws IOException {
        int readCount = this.socketChannel.read(this.input);

        //check whether the result is equal to -1, and close the connection if it is (thanks to EJP for comment)
        if(readCount == -1){
            this.socketChannel.close();
            System.out.println("Stream is closed. Close connection.");
            return;
        }

        if (readCount > 0) {
            processMessage(readCount);
        }

        if(this.clientMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("Bye")){
            this.socketChannel.close();
            //this.selectionKey.cancel(); //we don't need to cancel selectionKey if socketChannel is just closed (thanks to EJP for comment)
            System.out.println("Client said Bye. Close connection.");
            return;
        }

        this.state = EventHandler.Status.SENDING;
        this.selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE); //mark that we interested in writing
    }

    /**
     * Processing of the read message.
     *
     * @param readCount Number of bytes to read
     */
    synchronized void processMessage(int readCount) {
        this.input.flip();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(input.array(), 0, readCount))); // Assuming ASCII (bad assumption but simplifies the example)
        this.clientMessage = sb.toString().trim();
        this.input.clear();
        System.out.println("Client said: " + this.clientMessage);
    }

    /**
     * Sending response to client
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void send() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Answer to client: " + this.clientMessage);
        this.socketChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap((this.clientMessage + "\n").getBytes()));
        this.state = EventHandler.Status.READING;
        this.selectionKey.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ); //mark that we interested in reading
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Fields
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    final SocketChannel socketChannel;
    final SelectionKey selectionKey;

    ByteBuffer input = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    EventHandlerStatus state = EventHandler.Status.READING;
    String clientMessage = "";

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Enum to mark current status of EventHandler
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    enum Status {
        READING, SENDING
    }

}
```

Comment: Closing a SocketChannel doesn't close any other resources including the ServerSocketChannel.  IMHO I prefer blocking NIO, it's much simpler (no Selectors) and can be faster for a small number of sockets.

Comment: You must remove each selected key from the selectedKey set after processing it in each select() loop, or just clear the entire set each time around the loop. You don't need to wakeup the selector from within the select() thread. You don't need to cancel a key when you've just closed the channel it is associated with. You must check the read() result for -1 and if so close the channel.

Comment: guide, the code of which was used as the prototype can be found here http://jeewanthad.blogspot.ru/2013/02/reactor-pattern-explained-part-1.html

Comment: Your code and the code in that link both use the Reactor pattern, which is basically redundant, as NIO already is a design pattern of its own. Apart from that, the link isn't even slightly suitable as a basis for a non-blocking server. Don't use third-party third-rate sources. The typography alone should have put you off. Use the specifications and the tutorials. The errors in your implementation are strictly your own, and they concern matters which are all documented.